# GHDL bug with infinite process loop

Tags: fpga, vhdl

When I tested the code below with GHDL it didn't assign the value. I assumed it was a design issue, but in the Vivado simulator the value changed.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity tb_aes is
end tb_aes;


architecture test of tb_aes is
    signal done : boolean := false;
begin
    process is
    begin
        done <= true;

        if done then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end test;
```

BTW, it works fine with GHDL if I set a delay (`wait for 1 fs;`) in the process. Is this a bug in GHDL or in my design?

Version: GHDL 3.0.0-dev (2.0.0.r809.g35676f5d3) [Dunoon edition]

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with more detail.  When you said "it did not work", could you say _how_ it did not work, and what you expect "works" to be?  Did it throw an error, was everything flatlined, what?  BTW: it looks like you're not providing any explicit clocks for the `<=`.  If so, then it would be unsurprising that two different simulators would treat this condition differently.

Comment: @TimWescott Based on what I have learned, If we don't pass a sensitivity list to a process it will run again instantly after it is finished, And at the end of the process, the values to the signal should be assigned. Apparently, this doesn't happen in GHDL.

Comment: @TimWescott Question Edited but why two simulators should have different results? this way I'm not sure how my design would run on a real FPGA.

Comment: "If we don't pass a sensitivity list to a process it will run again instantly after it is finished," ... but what is meant by "instantly"?. If truly instantly, i.e. in the same delta cycle, then the delta cycle never finishes to allow the postponed assignment to happen. If "after 0 elapsed time", it would re-run in the next delta cycle after the assignment. Now I'm away from home and don't have the LRM handy so I won't claim this is what the LRM requires, but adding "wait for 0 fs;" is enough to get the expected behaviour. Guess we'll have to wait for David.

Comment: The signal update to done won't occur until the next simulation cycle, the waveform in the signal assignment has no after clause and defaults to 0 delay. Signal updates occur earlier in a simulation cycle than processes resume and subsequently suspend. The if condition is evaluated in the current simulation cycle and no wait statement is encountered, the process never suspends. It can be a wait for 0 time resolution units after the assignment, execution would suspend then resume in the next simulation cycle, a delta cycle with no simulation time change. I have the LRM on an iPad Mini, Brian.

Comment: So, this is technically a Vivado bug.

Comment: I think Vivado uses ModelSim.

Comment: Vivado Simulator is a descendent of Xilinx ISIM. Vivado also has the ability to integrate Modelsim. To get a signal update requires a subsequent simulation cycle, which can't happen until the process suspends. Wait statement timeout clauses aren't supported for synthesis in any event.